# ListView equivalent to iPhone table default table cell

Tags: android, listview

Is there an equivalent view structure to the iPhone default table cell? The default table cell formats an image (icon) and text in a nice looking way. Are there suggested equivalents for Android? Is there a sample somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Please define "a nice looking way"

Answer (score 1):

Surprised no one has responded.

From what I can tell there is no equivalent to the iPhone default table cell. You have to define your own view. There is no standard format. There are no UI design guidelines that are this specific. I found a layout that works in a discussion of  [Android 1.6 relative layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/ui-1.6.html). That layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="64dip"
android:padding="6dip">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/band"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="26dip"

android:layout_below="@+id/track"
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/track"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

android:gravity="top"
android:text="The Airborne Toxic Event" />

<TextView
android:id="@id/track"
android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="26dip"

android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/artwork"

android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:text="Sometime Around Midnight" />

<ImageView
android:id="@id/artwork"
android:layout_width="56dip"
android:layout_height="56dip"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

android:src="@drawable/fruit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```